# Sequelize: Destroy/Delete all records in the table

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Mocha for Unit tests.

When testing begins, I would like to delete all the previous records in a table.

What I have tried:

```
db.User.destroy({ force: true }).then(() => {
}).then(() => done());


db.User.destroy(
    {where: undefined},
    {truncate: false}
).then(() => {
    return 
}).then(() => done());


db.User.destroy({}).then(() => {
    return db.User.bulkCreate(users)
}).then(() => done());
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
 Error: Missing where or truncate attribute in the options parameter of model.destroy.
```

How do I delete/destroy all the records in a table?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can try using

```
db.User.destroy({
  where: {},
  truncate: true
})
```

Comment: @Coxer it isn't. You will receive an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Missing where or truncate attribute in the options parameter of model.destroy` error

Comment: you don't need where option.  `db.User.destroy({ truncate: true })` it's ok

Comment: `truncate: true` may not work if you have foreign key constraints in place. In that case, you can simply remove that clause.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067698/10908886) is safer solution.

Comment: I did that only `users.destroy({ where: {} })` and it works

Answer (score 10):

I was able to solve this problem with the code:

```
table.sync({ force: true });
```

This is a safer solution than the one proposed in [maheshiv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40958658).

Comment: this is a better solution if you want to reset the whole table and ids will count from 1 again, I found this answer is the safest answer for the testing purposes

Comment: Thank u  it helped me a lot while development b2c service

Answer (score 3):

It works for me: `db.User.truncate()`